# Cannot click the link in Selenium with WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I am running the below URL the error is showing in driver.get(URL) as the site is opened and  System.out.println("Site opened"); is not showing. Please help me why this error is showing.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver-v0.14.0-
win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.accu-chek.ca/");
System.out.println("Site opened");


driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/
div/nav/ul/li[5]/a")).click();
System.out.println("product registratio clicked");
```

Error:

```
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: https://www.accu-chek.ca/sites/g/files/iut106/f/js/js_WHPqc1IrlSx2Q7j8jBixXFftlSjp2Q9jeCOHNWbJqv8.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=netTimeout&u=https%3A//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html%3Fid%3DGTM-K2BV6VK&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=The%20server%20at%20www.googletagmanager.com%20is%20taking%20too%20long%20to%20respond.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '3169782', time: '2016-09-29 10:24:50 -0700'
System info: host: 'D-441001967', ip: '10.138.38.29', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\PR302559\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.dqtvUBQeSb9S, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=54.0.1, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=7412, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: 7d4f25a7-50e8-4f9c-9dc1-37cd4a48f656
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at mozila.main(mozila.java:10)
```

Comment: try latest gecko https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: If you are stuck by `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=netTimeout&u=https...` hold on the execution on this site. This issue is due to a error with WebDriver Specification which will be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your selenium jars, Firefox browser and gecko driver.

The same code is working fine in my side

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using Mozilla 54.0.1 , Selenium 3.5.o and gecko driver 18.0 . But this is showing same error. Can you please help in which version combination this is working fine.

Comment: I am currently usig 3.4.0 for both client and server jars of selenium. my firefox is latest as 55.0.2 and I am using gecko 0.18.0 .. this combination works for me

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me on selenium 3.5 and firefox 55.0. Your code is correct I don't understand why it create problem

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.accu-chek.ca/");
System.out.println("Site opened");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[5]/a")).click();
System.out.println("product registratio clicked");
```